# need translation of thomas merton for epitaph

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Can anyone help me to translate this into Latin:
“love is our true destiny. We do not find the meaning of life alone - we find it with another.”. Thank you 
It is an epitaph for my Dad, who was a Latin scholar.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Janet! It seems that you have created two user accounts. See [this page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for information about merging them. When you have your question assigned to a registered account, you will be able to comment on answers and otherwise use the site more flexibly. I converted your answer into a comment to Tom's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *Caritas nobis est sors vera. Vitam non explicandam nisi cum altero petimus.*

Roughly back-translated, 'Love for us is the true outcome. Life can't be explained except when we seek with another.'

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you put "vitam...explicandam" in the accusative?

Comment: Object of _petimus_. If you like, 'We seek a life not explainable except with a second person'.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom. What do you think about the following: “fatum verus amor noster. non inveniet vitam ipsi significatione- invenimus eam in alium”
or “amor est nostra sorte. non invenimus in vitae sensum per nos- invenimus eam cum alia.”

Comment: @Janet F  I am trying to think of a suitably delicate way to put it, but I had better be blunt and simply say that they are full of error — and rather long for an epitaph. One basic thing I will point out, though : that _caritas_ is the better word for 'love' in this case, lacking as it does the sexual connotations that usually attach to _amor_ —  this on the authority of Cicero, no less, at _de Part. Ora._ 88.

Comment: thank you once again, tom. no need to be delicate; both of those came from google translators. i like your translation a lot. i just have one more query as my deadline is today. would you be kind enough to comment on this:
Amor vera fortuna nostra est. Significationem vitae non solum invenimus. Invenimus eam cum alio"

Comment: It might just about serve as a literal translation, but if it isn't good Latin, it's at least  far better than the Google. To explain would be a lengthy job — for instance, you have to know idioms of possession and interest, when and which pronouns/adjectives, etc. to use and so on — and whether or not to use them. As in other languages, nuance can be disguised, rather as 'false friend' translations can occur. The 'looseness' of word order in Latin can often lead to ambiguity and, indeed, to pleonasm. Don't be overwhelmed by this : it takes years of reading to form good habits of composition!

Comment: your explanation sounds a lot like what my father might have said. he translated the scriptures from latin and ancient greek into english and was fastidious about meaning and nuance. that’s settled: i’m going with your translation, tom. thanks so much for all your help. it’s so kind of you.